# Car won't start following burning smell, low oil

Tags: engine, cranks-wont-run, low-oil, sonata

This is a 2011 Hyundai Sonata.

The car was running fine and I pulled into my friend's house and smelled something burning. I checked the oil and there was no oil so I put two quarts of oil and started driving.

It started making a ticking sound and shut off and will not turn on since. It will try turning over when jump-started but will not start.

Comment: Did the oil fall straight out the bottom ?  Sounds like the engine management computer has detected a significant problem and refuses to allow the car to start.  Time to read the error codes.

Comment: Where did the oil leak from? If there’s no leak that could mean your rings are bad and oil is getting into the cylinder, and being burnt